# Help with Interpreting and Resolving Irregular Hardware Error Messages on Debian GNU/Linux System

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, cpu, rsyslogd

I have a small problem here that I hope your kind help with. Recently these messages started appearing in my notification tray:

> Message from syslogd@oldsage at Apr 30 12:25:28 ... kernel:[9655.826192] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:6fd TIME 1682871928 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode a3

> Message from syslogd@oldsage at Apr 30 12:25:28 ... kernel:[9655.826180] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: 9000000000020151 Message from syslogd@oldsage at Apr 30 12:25:28 ... kernel:[ 9655.826187] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0

those two messages appear together. But there are no more signs of said error. My system continues to function normally. Although they do not pose direct problems, I am concerned about these messages. They appear from time to time, in irregular periods of several hours. My small computer knowledge does not include the Linux kernel, drivers, or hardware operation. So I pose my question here.

What does that mean and if possible how do I fix it?

To finish, I leave you the specifications of my PC. As you can see, it is something old.

Hardware:

- Motherboard: https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/eol/introduction.php?S_ID=518#overview
- CPU: 2 × Intel® Pentium® Dual CPU E2200 @ 2.20GHz
- RAM: 3,8 GiB de RAM Kingston KVR1333D3N9/4G
- GPU: VGA integrated
- generic USB peripherals.

Software:

- Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.20.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.78.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.2
- Kernel Version: 5.10.0-22-amd64
- OS Type: 64-bit

I checked the hardware of my PC, but I didn't find anything irregular. despite its age, the components look quite clean.

Comment: have you done a search for *linux kernel mce hardware error*

Comment: I have discovered a possible cause of the error. When the computer presented these reports it was in the hottest hours of the day, and since I am in a tropical area, maybe it got too hot.
In the coolest hours of the day these problems do not arise.

But this is only a hypothesis.

Comment: many of the results for searching that error do indicate that inadequate CPU cooling can be a factor

Comment: I checked the log in /var/log/kern.log
But I get an endless list of entries that I don't understand. I think this is where it says it's wrong.
I will continue to investigate and try to understand what these records mean.
By the time I post this, the messages appear again.

As an extra piece of information, I have 2 fan coolers installed on the PC. The CPU fan, and the SYS fan. with the SYS fan embedded in the chassis cover just above the CPU fan. Blowing both on the processor.

Although I don't know if this is useful for the case.

Comment: try monitoring your CPU temperature - I believe `lm-sensors` will help with that

Comment: The temperature stabilizes at 80 Cº when the PC is idle. And it goes down when I start using some software. I guess the motherboard keeps it at 80 Cº.

Comment: the specs for that processor specify a MAX temperature of 73.3ºC - your cooling solution is inadequate

Comment: I will make changes to my cooling system. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I have applied maximum underclocking to my CPU. The temperature was reduced between 60°C and 70°C. Now I'll wait and see if those messages don't appear again.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing multiple solutions to the cooling system and waiting. I can conclude that the hardware problems were due to excessive heat in the CPU.

Now that the temperature is lower, the problem notifications no longer appear.

I have also found to my surprise that modern processors are more tolerant of high temperatures. Apparently the linux kernel has established its parameters to the tolerable margins of these new processors (around 80 Cº). and these settings regulate the speed of the fancoolers.

which for an old processor like the one I have is inefficient. Hence the problems.

Keep that in mind for those who have old PCs, Watch the temperature!

Comment: I don't think the kernel manages the fan speed - I think the BIOS does this ... but I could be wrong.

Comment: I also think that's the case, but it happened to me on one occasion that a bug in the debian bullseye kernel, when it went to "sleep", messed up the entire system (including the bios).

It did not destroy any software or information, but the pc did not boot even with the bios, I had to remove the hard drive and format the root partition with a sata-usb adapter. Then it was that I was able to run the pc normally again.

That's why I think the kernel affects all hardware simply by "existing" on disk. But this last one is just my speculation.